# If statement VBA Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-2010

Ok so I am calculating rates with an if Statement

---

$2 kWh +
0. First 150 kWh per kW @ $0.4

1. Next 150 kWh per kW @ $0.25
2. Next 150 kWh per kW @ $0.10
3. Additional kWh @ $0.05

---

I want to have three rows

- kWh - Use (kWuse
          - 50kW, 160kW, 305kW, 500kW,
- kWh - Price (kWprice
- kWh - Cost (kWcost

Use will be how many Kw they use. Price will be the IF statement. And cost will be the calculation of the two.

But all I need help with is the Price if statement.

Thanks,

Comment: This is typical use for a VLookup, and I suspect it would be faster than VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that there is a 2 dollar base charge + the kWh rate (4 pricing teirs), then here is a function that will give you the cost if you give it the usage. Since the rates are fixed at 3 tiers, you already know what the cost is for 150, 300, and 450 kWh, so I used that in my function.

With this, all you need is 2 columns. The usage, and the price (this formula).

```
Function GetCost(ByVal usage As Double) As Double

' $2 kWh base +
'First 150 kWh per kW @ $0.4
'Next 150 kWh per kW @ $0.25
'Next 150 kWh per kW @ $0.10
'Additional kWh @ $0.05

If usage > 450 Then
    GetCost = 114.5 + ((usage - 450) * 0.05)
ElseIf usage > 300 Then
    GetCost = 99.5 + ((usage - 300) * 0.1)
ElseIf usage > 150 Then
    GetCost = 62 + ((usage - 150) * 0.25)
Else
    GetCost = 2 + (usage * 0.4)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please let me know if this works or how you would like it adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Dim Price as Double
If kwPrice < 150 Then 
    Price = 0.4
ElseIf kwPrice >= 150 And kwPrice <= 300 Then
    Price = 0.25
ElseIf kwPrice > 300 Then
    Price = 0.1
Else
    Price = 0.05
End If
```

Hopefully that will get you started.